# Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI for Data table

Tags: android

My fragment implements the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
interface to query android.provider.ContactsContract.**Contacts.CONTENT_URI** and return some data.

But since i wanted lower level data(one row for every phone number), i changed the code to query the android.provider.ContactsContract.**Data.CONTENT_URI** instead.

Most of the columns in the Contacts class were available in the Data class, because of implicit joins(as described in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html). So all i had to do was edit my selection and projection strings to replace the "Contacts." with "Data."

For example, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY became Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY

Now the only problem is the search function. Earlier i could use the Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, which enables the type-to-filter functionality on Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

But now, i cannot find an alternative for Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI in the Data class. Any ideas on how i can let the user do a search in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative for Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI in the Data class. But the same type-to-filter functionality can be achieved by editing the SELECTION string of the cursorLoader. Append the required filter condition to the SELECTION string with a placeholder as below :

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
String SELECTION_FILTERED =
            (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Data.DISPLAY_NAME) +
            "<>''" + " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE +"'" +
            " AND " + (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Data.DISPLAY_NAME) +
            " LIKE ? ";
```

Then add the search term into the selectionArgs(the second last parameter to the CursorLoader constructor) :

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                ContactsQuery.CONTENT_URI,
                ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
                ContactsQuery.SELECTION_FILTERED,
                new String[] {"%"+mSearchTerm+"%"},
                ContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);
```

The cursorLoader has to be restarted every time the user enters a character into the seach box :

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(
                        ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID, null, PhoneContactsListFragment.this);
```

This will ensure that the constructor gets called with the new search term every time there is a change.